# Next.js 14 generateStaticParamsparams parameter returning undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm referencing this doc to try to get params from the URL in generateStaticParams: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#generate-params-from-the-bottom-up

This is my route: `app/[productType]/[coverType]/[make]/page.tsx`

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
export async function generateStaticParams({
  params: { productType, coverType },
}: {
  params: { productType: string; coverType: string };
}) {
  console.log('GenerateStaticParams:', { productType, coverType });
  const makeData = await getAllMakes({
    type: productType,
    cover: coverType,
  });

  return makeData.filter(Boolean).map((make) => ({
    make: make,
  }));
}
```

`productType` and `coverType` are both undefined. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it because I'm not generating from the top down?